# How to get roles from principal in Apache Shiro?

Tags: authorization, shiro

I am a bit stuck here.

Using a very simple Shiro configuration with jdbcRealm:

```
[main]
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# Create JDBC realm.
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm

# Configure JDBC realm datasource.
ds = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
ds.databaseName = pg_sensor
***
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

# Configure JDBC realm SQL queries.
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name = ?
# user id is a user Role )
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?
```

So, I use `userid` as a role to do authorization in the code. 
In one scenario I need to get role name to proceed.

Can anyone suggest how to do that from the `Principal` (`SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()`)?

I guess we need to use `getRoles()` withing `SimpleAccount` class, but not able to connect it with `Principal`.

Answer (score 4):

Before anything, some comment about your shiro.ini:

### Role query

First of all, your `jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery` does not really make sense: you are supposed to fetch the roles not the users for this query.

Assuming you have tables

```
CREATE TABLE user{
    id          INTEGER,
    username    VARCHAR,
    password    VARCHAR
}

CREATE TABLE user_role{
    id          INTEGER,
    role_name   VARCHAR,
    username    VARCHAR
}
```

your queries would like:

```
# Configure JDBC realm SQL queries.
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?
# user id is a user Role )
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM user_role WHERE username = ?
```

### Principal

I'm assuming that your subject is already successfully authenticated. So far, `SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()` will only return the *login* or *username*, anything which identify your user but nothing more. In my above example, it would return the value stored in `username` column.

### Role check

I think, you are rather looking *does this authenticated user has role "MyRole"?*. In this case, you can have a look around `SecurityUtils.getSubject().hasRole("MyRole")`. As far as I know, there is no way to list all the roles a subject currently has. You can only check if the subject has such or such role

Feel free to comment if I misunderstood your question